# Flex 4.6, AIR 3.5, desktop app, navigateToURL, _self

Tags: apache-flex, browser, air

I have a desktop AIR app built with Flex 4.6 and Air 3.5.  I use navigateToURL to launch a URL in the default browser, works fine:

```
var request : URLRequest = new URLRequest  ( "http://localhost:8890/test.html" );
var urlVariables : URLVariables = new URLVariables ();
urlVariables['activity'] = "xyz.json";
request.data = urlVariables;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
navigateToURL(request, "_self");
```

The app lets the user construct some JSON content (xyz.json), then test it in a test rig (test.html).

The second and subsequent times I do this, I get a new tab (I'm using Chrome).  What I want is for it to appear in the same tab as the last one.  Note that I've used "_self".  If I pass any string I get the same result.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe it is possible to force browser to reuse same tab - that would be browser behaviour, not AIR behaviour (ie: you would change the expected behaviour in browser settings; eg: always open content in new tab).

Answer (score 0):

I believe from a desktop app when you invoke NavigateToURL() it will force a new window (container) to launch.

If you can you could create a separate 'receiver' page on the server to receive the data (invisible to the user) Then launch a 'viewer' page with NavigateToURL that would contain an ajax script to check and update the data received from the 'receiver' page.

I would check out URLLoader() Class. I use this many times for my web service scripts.